# Emojis generated by emojize doesn't show in email

Tags: python, email

I'm using `email` and `smtplib` libraries to send an email. I'm trying to include emojis in this email, by using `emojize`.

Basically, I'm doing this :

```
my_emoji = emoji.emojize(":thumbs_up:")

my_message = f"blabla {my_emoji} blabla"
```

Then the message is sent using `smtplib` and `email`. It works, but not always. 
Some emojis will appears in the email correctly, but some will not. For example, :thumbs_up: works, but :heart: doesn't. Instead of the actual emoji, there will be written ":heart:" in the mail.

I don't think my code is the problem, that's why I only shown a sample. I think it has something to do with encoding, unicode or something like that (I barely know anything in those fields)

Can you help me ? Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem. The heart should be :red_heart:. Make sure the spelling is correct.